# c++ Arbitrary number of threads, fatal error

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2013

I have a function that acts exclusively on an instance of an structure and as far as I can tell it's thread safe.  I have a vector of these objects and I want to create a thread for each instance.  I've attempted to do it as follows but I get a fatal error.  I am trying to work out if this is coming from the way I'm setting up threads or the function I'm threading.  Is this a reasonable way to setup threads?

```
void massThreadSectors(vector<skyImage>& images)
{
    int size = images.size();
    cout << size << endl << endl;
    vector<thread> vecThread(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        vecThread.at(i) = thread(proccessSectors, images[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; ++i) { vecThread.at(i).join(); cout << i << endl; }
}
```

The debug output is:

```
The thread 0x295c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in cppImageProccess.exe.

Press Break to debug the program or Continue to terminate the program.

The thread 0x1e08 has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 0x2824 has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 0x2828 has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 0x2834 has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 0x2830 has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The program '[6120] cppImageProccess.exe' has exited with code 3 (0x3).
```

Comment: Last loop: `i <= size` -> `i < size`

Comment: right in the join loop, thanks that seems to have fixed it!!

Comment: Not in the `join` loop, at least not in the one you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be to try to get out of the habit of writing explicit loops with explicit indexing when you can. In this case, you certainly can:

```
vector<thread> vecThread(size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    vecThread.at(i) = thread(proccessSectors, images[i]);
}
```

I'd prefer to write this more like:

```
std::vector<thread> threads;

std::transform(images.begin(), images.end(), 
    std::back_inserter(threads),
    [](skyImage &i) { return thread(processSectors, i); });
```

Likewise, your loop that does the joining would be done with `std::for_each`:

```
std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), [](thread &t) { t.join(); });
```

Alternatively, you use use range-based `for` loops for both:

```
for (auto &i : images)
    threads.emplace_back(thread(processSectors, i));

for (auto &t : threads)
    t.join();
```

Either way, the loop is "automated" to the point that it's difficult to get things wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I normally use range-based loops in python but I hadn't quite figured them out in c++